# Angular 6 build issue

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

```
    ERROR in : "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" [ERROR ->]let-rowz="$implicit" let-index="i
ndex">
      <tr *ngIf="!(datePicker.onlyCurrentMonth && rowz[0].sec")
: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" let-rowz="$implicit" [ERROR ->]let-index="i
ndex">
      <tr *ngIf="!(datePicker.onlyCurrentMonth && rowz[0].secondary && rowz[6].s
`ec")
```

I am getting this error when iam using --aot build, It is working without --aot in Angular 6.

Kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Actually problem is not with the code. It works without --aot.

Comment: Have you tried to use ng-template to replace the template?

Comment: In my code I'm using <ng-template> only. But in --aot it is showing like that. I am using ngx-bootstrap with angular 6. Is there is any problem with that.

Comment: I think there might be an error in the code even if it works without --aot. You might just be lucky to use the code in a way that works when using the jit compiler

Comment: Is it possible to get version mismatch for ngx-bootstrap with angular 6?

Comment: try to install : `"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"`

Comment: I tried this, But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements.

please replace `template` with `ng-template`.

Comment: <ng-template #template>
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:green">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Total</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
          <span class="modalClose" class="modalClose" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:white;">
        <div>
          <p>Modal Body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

Comment: I already using ng-template only. But still iam getting this issue.

Comment: please try to install this version:  `"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"`

Comment: and then did you install node_module again?

Comment: Yes.. I did that and also the package.json is updated to "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"

Comment: @Arunkumar in the code you post you do not use ng-template